# How to require a LaTeX version that provides the new hooks management system?

Tags: latex-base, hooks, lthooks

A class of mine is loading the `biblatex` package if the user uses a given option. For this, the class used to rely on `\AtEndPreamble{\RequirePackage{biblatex}}` and I guess it used to work nicely. It isn't the case any more as shown by the following MCE:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndPreamble{\usepackage{biblatex}}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

which returns the following (first) error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...ndpreambleonly \ifnum \blx@hyperref 
                                                  =\thr@@ \else \ifnum \blx@...
l.503   \let\do\noexpand}
```

the *File List* being:

```
 article.cls    2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
etoolbox.sty    2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
biblatex.sty    2020/12/31 v3.16 programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)
pdftexcmds.sty    2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
 ltxcmds.sty    2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
kvoptions.sty    2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  blx-dm.def    2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
blx-compat.def    2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
biblatex.def    2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
standard.bbx    2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
 numeric.bbx    2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
 numeric.cbx    2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex citation style (PK/MW)
biblatex.cfg
l3backend-pdftex.def    2021-01-09 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
 english.lbx    2020/12/31 v3.16 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
   expl3.sty    2021-01-09 L3 programming layer (loader) 
blx-case-expl3.sty    2020/12/31 v3.16 expl3 case changing code for biblatex
  xparse.sty    2020-10-27 L3 Experimental document command parser
 ***********
```

As a workaround and, nowadays maybe a better practise, one can make use of the new hooks management system:

```
\documentclass{article}
\AddToHook{env/document/begin}[mydoc/loadbiblatex]{%
  \RequirePackage{biblatex}%
}
\DeclareHookRule{env/document/begin}{mydoc/loadbiblatex}{before}{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

which compiles like a charm.

Hence, I'm inclined to use these hooks in a new version of my class. But I'd like to ensure people who would use this new version would have an enough recent version of LaTeX that provides these hooks. Is it enough to specify in the class:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2020-10-01]
```

this date being given by:

```
texdef -t latex fmtversion
```

Comment: why do you want to load biblatex only at the end of the preamble? For hyperref I understand such a setup but biblatex should work fine in the class directly. Beside this: you test for the format version with `\@ifl@t@r\fmtversion`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Because the class doesn't load `fontenc` which, AFAIK, needs to be the first loaded (with `inputenc`, automatically loaded nowadays) and I want to ensure `biblatex` is loaded after it.

Comment: Or you just check whether `\AddToHook` is available for your code, if so use the new variant, else stick to `\AtEndPreamble`. This way your class continues to work with older versions, and works as intended with recent LaTeX kernels. So `\ifdefined\AddToHook <new-code>\else <old-code>\fi`

Comment: @Skillmon Indeed. I planned to provide the old code, but with a based on the LaTeX version because, perhaps wrongly, I had the feeling it was a cleaner way to proceed.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer About `\@ifl@t@r\fmtversion`, okay, but what is the threshold date to rely on?

Comment: why does the order of fontenc and biblatex matter that seems odd?

Comment: You seemed to say you needed to use AtEndPreamble to load biblatex late to ensure it is loaded after fontenc. If you mean that I am just surprised that is needed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle AFAIK, `fontenc` should be the first loaded: isn't it? If so, `biblatex` should be loaded after it, or am I missing something?

Comment: No I can't think of any reason at all why fontenc would need to come before biblatex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle And shouldn't `fontenc` be loaded before other packages (than `biblatex`)? I'm pretty sure I read in a trusted source `fontenc` should be one of the first loaded packages.

Comment: There are very few packages that have any dependency on fontenc (which doesn't really do anything other that set the default encoding)  I think French babel complains if it detects OT1 so says T1 should be loaded earlier but actually that  is just an over eager check, all that is really necessary is that T1 encoding is selected before the document starts.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle french checks \AtBeginDocument for OT1.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Indeed about French `babel` complains if it detects OT1 but, indeed, it actually requests only to add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to the preamble, not necessarily before `babel`. But the `babel`'s documentation gives an example with `fontenc` before `babel` and, AFAIK, `babel` has to be loaded late anyway (with some exceptions such as `hyperref`).

Comment: but babel has a direct connection to font encodings as hyphenation patterns are tied to font encodings so that connection is understandable. I can't think of any reason why biblatex (or most packages) would have any dependency on font encodings.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay for `biblatex` and `fontenc`. But not for `csquotes` and `inputenc` (the latter might be loaded explicitly by someone who would want e.g. `latin1` encoding instead of `utf8`): `csquotes` requires to be loaded after `inputenc`. Hence, it could be useful for my class to load `csquotes` at the end of the preamble and, for this, to rely on the new hooks management system.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé the user may have already loaded csquotes so you loading it late can't force anything as your load will be ignored, seems like it would be better to request csquotes get fixed not to demand that inputenc is loaded early. But anyway you can ignore me chatting the answer to your question is yes that date check is correct.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle About my load that would be ignored, I'm using `\AtEndPreamble{\@ifpackageloaded{csquotes}{}{\RequirePackage{csquotes}}}` (`\AtEndPreamble` currently but subject to change). Sorry, I don't understand "it would be better to request `csquotes` get fixed".